# "click" listener gets execute multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create the table which creates rows using ajax. the problem is that when i assigned the "click" listener based on the class name it is getting called multiple time

my code is

```
function fn_getAlertRules(parentRowId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: anyURL,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        // create row to add to parent table's row
        var s_rulesHtmlString = '<tr><td colspan="3" class="rules-parent-tr"><table><tbody>';
        $.each(data, function(i, name) {
        s_rulesHtmlString += '<tr class="rule-tr">';
        s_rulesHtmlString += '<td class="eventid-td">Rule ID:'+ name.RuleId+'<span>' + name.OccuredEventId + '</span></td>';
        s_rulesHtmlString += '<td>' + name.Name + '</td><td>' + name.RuleDate + '</td>';
        s_rulesHtmlString += '</tr>';
        });
        s_rulesHtmlString += '</tbody></table></td></tr>';
        // add row below parent tr
        $(parentRowId).parent().after(s_rulesHtmlString);
        $(".rule-tr").on("click", "td", function(event) {
            // this code blocks get executed multiple times
        });
    });
}
```

can anybody please tell me, why it is getting called multiple time ?

Comment: How many times are you calling that function?

Comment: fn_getAlertRules get called only one time ! only code inside .on("click") gets called as many time as number of rows are present

Comment: The pattern `$(".rule-tr").on("click", "td", function(event)` replaced the old `live` event, which was used to bind to elements even after the dom tree was changed. So, on each ajax call you are adding the listeners to the `click` event over and over.

Comment: ok ! so u r saying that i should not go by this manner!  can u suggest me any good approach ?

Comment: how many times the callback is called? One for each row, 2 times ...?

Comment: @Alepac,  depends on number of rows, if there are 10 rows then it gets called 10 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding `click` event in each (**loop**) and event is binded as many times as loop is executed, that is why you get repeated click events. You can delegate the click event to parent of elements to be added or `document` before ajax call and event will be binded automatically to dynamically added element being added in done function. You can read more about event delegation using on [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
function fn_getAlertRules(parentRowId) {
    $(document).on("click", ".rule-tr td", function(event) {
       // this code blocks get executed multiple times 
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: anyURL,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        // create row to add to parent table's row
        var s_rulesHtmlString = '<tr><td colspan="3" class="rules-parent-tr"><table><tbody>';
        $.each(data, function(i, name) {
        s_rulesHtmlString += '<tr class="rule-tr">';
        s_rulesHtmlString += '<td class="eventid-td">Rule ID:'+ name.RuleId+'<span>' + name.OccuredEventId + '</span></td>';
        s_rulesHtmlString += '<td>' + name.Name + '</td><td>' + name.RuleDate + '</td>';
        s_rulesHtmlString += '</tr>';
        });
        s_rulesHtmlString += '</tbody></table></td></tr>';
        // add row below parent tr
        $(parentRowId).parent().after(s_rulesHtmlString);       
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have multiple table rows with the same class assigned to it. If you want to get it executed only for the item that is clicked, assign a unique id to it.

Comment: i am not sure this is a problem... because i thought similar and had debug for same, but in  `$(".rule-tr").on("click", "td", function(event) {
            // using $(this) i get only that td which is clicked
        });`

Comment: He can use this as well which indicate the row clicked instead of all rows which share same class name.

Comment: @rahularyansharma Build the dom element with things like `var td = $('<td></td>');`, and then add the click event on that particular item with `td.click(function(event) { });`

Comment: @rahularyansharma Not quite what I was saying. Have a look at this updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/cBBQF/6/

Comment: @Candide so you add click event on new row and its working ? what next  ? Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

I think a solution (that optimize performance too) is to use [delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). So you may add a single event handler on the parent row (or table) and act depending on the `event.target` object.

**UPDATE:** Moreover be carefull that the selector `$(".rule-tr")` append the event handler even to rows having different parent_id so a better solution could be `$(parent_Id + " .rule-tr")` supposing the parent_id is a string in the form `"#parent_id"`

Answer (score 0):

Connect the on click event to the last `<tr>` only, after the ajax

```
$(".rule-tr :last").on("click", "td", function(event) {
            // this code blocks get executed multiple times
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it to avoid repeat bind the click event

```
$(".rule-tr").unbind();
$(".rule-tr").on("click", "td", function(event) {
            // this code blocks get executed multiple times
        });
```